# Claims based authentication and adding users

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I set up claims based authentication on one of our web applications. It works with forms authentication. There are 20,000 users that need to access to this site but I don't know how to add them. Do I have to give every one of them Full Read permissions on the web application? Then how can I give them write permissions on the lists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guess if you had groups and users to the groups it would be much easier to manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own answer to my question:

I gave **Full Read** to **All Authenticated Users** on the web application level then added **All Authenticated Users** to **Site Members**.

Comment: please mark your answer as correct answer